# wordpress: Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 56623104)

Tags: wordpress, php-7, memory-limit

I have a website in wordpress, under PHP 7.0. My server logs are filled with:

```
wordpress: Fatal error:  Out of memory (allocated 56623104)
```

My question is where is this value 56623104(~56M) taken from? Where should I look?

In my php.ini I have:

```
php -i | grep memory_limit
memory_limit => 2048M => 2048M
```

In wp-config.php I have:

```
define( 'WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '256M' );
define( 'WP_MAX_MEMORY_LIMIT', '1024M' );
```

Also I have enough free memory:

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          3945       2848       1096          0         57       1298
-/+ buffers/cache:       1492       2453
```

Comment: how much memory do you have on your system? you can try phpinfo() and see what's your memory limit!

Comment: I do this: php -i | grep memory_limit. Is the same.

Comment: ok here's the thing, memory is allocated step-by-step, so in each step, php requests for 56623104 (this much) memory in your case, so we don't know how many steps were taken to allocate, it looks like theres an infinite loop going on that is requesting memory repeatedly, and at one point, it fails, so there's some problem in some code (plugin perhaps)

Comment: so maybe at that moment, my free memory was less than requested?

Comment: yes, the problem seems to be in the code, or may be it tries to process a very large object, also it is possible that this is no error at all, if you're running it live and you have like 50 simultaneous users, this problem can easily occur... so in that case you might need to increase your server's memory

Answer (score 0):

Create a new file called anything like you (with php) so phpinfo.php for example. Then put this in:

```
<?php
phpinfo();
?>
```

Upload it to your site and open it in the browser, check that the memory is actually 256. Pop it in a sub directory and check its the same there.

Comment: how does the memory change in a sub-directory?